# Configure ejabberd to use streamhost proxy

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, socks

I want to configure ejabberd to use an external SOCKS 5 Bytestream server for file transfer according to protocol [XEP-0065](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0065.html). My questions are:

1. How can i configure ejabberd (or any other jabber server) to advertise such a service to clients.
2. Where do i find an S5B implementation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ejabberd [supports `XEP-0065` out of the box](http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#modproxy) using a built-in module.

To enable it, you have to uncomment the related clause in the configuration file, tweak its settings according to your setup and restart the server.